# Installed a password manager and now safari won't autofill

Tags: safari, catalina

I installed a password manager from the App Store and since then my autofill in Safari has stopped working. I cannot uninstall the application as I do not have root permission. Does anyone know how to turn my autofill back on?

I have looked at the autofill tab under safari > preferences but the options there are blanked out so I cannot turn them on.

I am using macOS Catalina

[image]

Comment: How did you install it without permission? root is almost never used on macOS, so I presume you mean admin permission. What's the app?

Comment: yes admin permission sorry. Its the keeper Password Manager @Tetsujin

Comment: If you have permission to install and app then you have the permission to remove it. I think you need to explain more detailed what you have done and tried.

Comment: the system trusts installations from the App Store but doesn't give admin permissions to delete applications

Comment: @NathanThomas Then something is wrong I can delete apps that I have installed from the AppStore

Answer (score -1):

To cleanly undelete apps you need to use an 'uninstaller' app.  I suggest either [Remove-It](http://www.osxbytes.com/remove-it.html?forcedownload) or [App Cleaner & Uninstaller](https://nektony.com/help/app-cleaner).  You will need to use your admin password when deleting apps with either of these tools.